# Send email with attachment suddenly stopped working

Tags: email, google-apps-script, email-attachments

I have a piece of code that converts a spreadsheet page into a pdf, then emails it. It has been working flawlessly for over 2 years. Now, all of a sudden the emails aren't being sent and when I run the code manually to find out what is going on, I get **"Invalid argument:attachments (line xxx, file "Code")"**.
I've compared the sendEmail function to google script's examples and it looks fine. As I said, it's been working for a long time and I haven't made any recent changes to any of the code.
Here are the offending lines, any clues much appreciated.

```
    MailApp.sendEmail({ //send the email with attachment
    to: "example@wtf.com.au", //email changed to protect the innocent
    subject: subject, //Service Report
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
    body: body,
    inlineImages:{Logo: logoBlob}, //insert the logo into the email
    name:"Service", //sender name
    attachments:[theBlob], //attach the report
    });
```

Comment: If you make a copy of the code is it working ?

Comment: Can you show how you retrieved `theBlob`?

Comment: This is probably not the problem but  the last comma in here `attachments:[theBlob],` should be removed.  It would be helpful if you could provide a [mcve] so that we could verify the problem.  This site has spent a great deal of time and effort to show you [ask] better questions. Try taking the [tour] and learn how to help yourself get better answers

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Cooper, I added to the code snippet so that it could be run on it's own. When I did this the snippet ran perfectly, not reproducing the error. So I looked at whether the "Blob" rather than the "attachment:" was the problem. While looking further up the code, and running the full code several times, nothing looked wrong but same error. I walked away from it for a couple of days, then came back to it today and it now works perfectly again!